# Is it possible to have two sources for a mount?

Tags: fedora, mount, ftp, smb

I have NAS which is accessible via both SMB and FTP.  I currently have the share mounted on my Fedora 33 laptop using curlftpfs, but I'd like to know if it's possible to configure it to first try mounting the share using SMB and fall back to curlftpfs if that fails.  This way it would mount using the much faster SMB protocol when I'm at home and only fall back to the slower FTP protocol when I'm not connected to my home network.

EDIT: I'm using SystemD Automount to manage the mount.

This is how my mounts are specified in `etc/fstab`:

```
dave:xxxxxxx@davef.dyndns-at-home.com/music /mnt/Music  fuse.curlftpfs  noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,allow_other,_netdev,umask=133,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10 0 0
//192.168.1.201/music   /mnt/Music  smb3    noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000,_netdev,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,credentials=/etc/music-creds   0 0
```

Comment: You could mount the FTP one first and then mount the SMB one on top of it. So if the SMB mount fails, you see the FTP one.

Comment: @muru, I just tried that and I still only saw the FTP mount.  I should have mentioned that I'm using SystemD Automount to manage the mount.

Comment: Yes, the mounts must be ordered correctly for that to work.